# Rust options, implementing a custom "expect" method

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm very new to Rust, so I must warn you, I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing. In a rust-sfml example (irrelevant to question) I saw this Options pattern which is apparently a common one:

```
let ballSoundBuffer = match SoundBuffer::new("resources/ball.wav") {
    Some(ballSoundBuffer)   => ballSoundBuffer,
    None                    => panic!("Cannot load Ball sound buffer.")
};
```

Later I learned about the `expect()` function so the above can be replaced with:

```
 let ballSoundBuffer = SoundBuffer::new("resources/ball.wav").expect("Cannot load Ball sound buffer.")
```

For the sake of exercise I wanted to implement something like the expect method myself, as a standalone method, and came up with something like this:

```
fn checkOption<T>(obj: Option<T>, err: &str) -> T {
    match obj {
        Some(o) => return o,
        None => panic!(err)
    }
}
```

The goal was to do something like:

```
let tmp = SoundBuffer::new("resources/ball.wav");
let ballSoundBuffer = checkOption(tmp, "Cannot load Ball sound buffer.");
```

I'm using generics because I also want the method to work with other resources than SoundBuffer (but they also use the same Options pattern when loading them). However, this doesn't work at all:

```
src/main.rs:20:24: 20:27 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
src/main.rs:20         None => panic!(err)
                                  ^~~
<std macros>:1:1: 12:62 note: in expansion of panic!
src/main.rs:20:17: 21:6 note: expansion site
src/main.rs:17:51: 22:2 note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 17:50...
src/main.rs:17 fn checkOption<T>(obj: Option<T>, err: &str) -> T {
src/main.rs:18     match obj {
src/main.rs:19         Some(o) => return o,
src/main.rs:20         None => panic!(err)
src/main.rs:21     }
src/main.rs:22 }
src/main.rs:20:24: 20:27 note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected `&str`, found `&str`)
src/main.rs:20         None => panic!(err)
                                  ^~~
<std macros>:1:1: 12:62 note: in expansion of panic!
src/main.rs:20:17: 21:6 note: expansion site
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
<std macros>:3:1: 3:28 note: ...so that the type `&str` will meet its required     lifetime bounds
<std macros>:3 $ crate:: rt:: begin_unwind (
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<std macros>:1:1: 12:62 note: in expansion of panic!
src/main.rs:20:17: 21:6 note: expansion site
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I have no idea what to do with this :( I was hoping someone more knowledgeable could point out my mistake.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I filed an [issue a while back](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23685) about the poor error message with a non-string as the first argument to `panic!`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to fix your function: The first is to add a `'static` lifetime annotation on `err`:

```
fn checkOption<T>(obj: Option<T>, err: &'static str) -> T {
    match obj {
        Some(o) => return o,
        None => panic!(err)
    }
}
```

However, this means you can only use values of type `&'static str` (i.e. string constants, effectively) for `err`.

The second way is to do what `expect` does and call `panic!("{}", err)` instead of `panic!(err)`:

```
fn checkOption<T>(obj: Option<T>, err: &str) -> T {
    match obj {
        Some(o) => return o,
        None => panic!("{}", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I searched for hours before posting and of course I found the issue 5min after posting:

`panic!(err)` has to be `panic!("{}", err)`

Maybe it's because I'm so new, but that error msg was very confusing...

Comment: Yeah, the error message is awful. I only figured it out quickly because I vaguely recalled that panic messages need to be `Send` and `&str` isn't `Send`. Technically it has all the information, but it's buried in scary and verbose fluff. Maybe file a issue on Github.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `panic!` needs the string supplied to it to have static lifetime.

Changing your signature to `fn checkOption<T>(obj: Option<T>, err: &'static str) -> T` compiles and does what you want.